# Omnet++ inet::EtherAppCli not found

Tags: omnet++

Is there a simple way to create a project, similar to inet>examples>lans, not under inet>examples>lans, but in a separate project and workspace? And what steps must I do for it?
I try to create my own model like the "Two hosts" one in a new project folder with project references to inet folder (with Omnet++ 5.1, Inet 3.6, Windows 7 pro 64 bits). 
There is no problem to create the ned file. The Etherhost underlying model with EtherAppCli and EtherAppServ are found in the ned file. I have no errors by building the project.
But, I have always the error "Class "inet::EtherAppCli" not found" when I run the model. Can someone help me to solve this problem ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project` | `Properties` | `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | select your source dir, then `Options...` | `Link` tab and try to select `Link with libraries from referenced projects`.

Comment: The option "link with libraries from referenced projects was already activated". But I detect a warning by the building of the project:    
Warning (1 item)
Invalid project path: Include path not found (C:\Programmes\Omnetpp\omnatpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\src
Resource: inet
Type: Path Entry Problem.                                                                
 Where should I act to solve this problem ? Many thanks

Comment: Did you select `Add include paths exported from referenced projects` in `Compile` tab in Makemake options? By the way: you have written that there were no errors during building your project.

Comment: The problem still remains the same with these options. I have no errors in Building my project. However, I have a warning that I had not previoulsy detected in "Problems".
When I go into inet>examples>lans, and I build the project for twohosts example, I have the same warning message as the one in my project:
"Warning (1 item) Invalid project path: Include path not found (C:\Programmes\Omnetpp\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\src)"
Hence my question: Can the problem encountered in my project eventually come from INET 3.6.0 install options ? Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

My advices for your problem are the following:

1. Is there a folder named "Includes" is your project (you can see it in eclipse)? If no, create a new project  in Eclipse `New` | `Project` | `OMNeT++`, and paste your files there. (You don't have to do this in the examples folder of inet.)
2. Check if there is no any error when you `make` your project in the console. If there are any, they are often explicit. If there is no error:

   - in Eclipse, delete the "out" folder
   - in the console, go into your project directory and type `opp_makemake -f` (`-f` for force) and then `make`
   - in Eclipse, right click on your project and click on `Build project`
3. Check that all the functions defined in EtherAppCli.h are implemented in EtherAppCli.cc

I hope that one of these solutions will solve the error.