# Omnet++ fatal error: 'inet/.../something.h' file not found

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am trying to create a new project from Windows 10/11 in Omnet++ 5.7 referenced to inet (Right Clicked on First Project - > Properties - > Project References - > Marked Inet) but it fails because it can't find the inet's classes.
I tried to recompile everything (including inet after adding my .cc files), but nothing seems to work.
That's a sample of how I included the files in my .cc classes:

```
#include "inet/common/INETDefs.h"
#include "inet/common/geometry/common/Coord.h"
#include "inet/common/packet/Packet.h"
```

This is my error:

```
23:26:01 **** Incremental Build of configuration release for project project ****
make MODE=release all 
cd src && /usr/bin/make
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/cyb/Desktop/omnetpp-5.7/samples/project/src'
gpsr/Gpsr.cc
In file included from gpsr/Gpsr.cc:22:
gpsr/Gpsr.h:23:10: fatal error: 'inet/common/INETDefs.h' file not found
#include "inet/common/INETDefs.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:112: ../out/clang-release/src/gpsr/Gpsr.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/cyb/Desktop/omnetpp-5.7/samples/project/src'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
"make MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

23:26:04 Build Failed. 3 errors, 0 warnings. (took 2s.194ms)
```

I've already tried to recreate a new "makemake" file, but still this error occurs.
I also tried the suggestions I found here [Omnet++ inet::EtherAppCli not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700952/omnet-inetetherappcli-not-found) and here [Omnet++ fatal error: 'inet/common/INETDefs.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69209072/omnet-fatal-error-inet-common-inetdefs-h-file-not-found) . Same error occurs when I create a new project from 0 or even if I use a different version of Omnet++/Inet (I tried omnet 4,5 and 6) or O.S (such as Windows or Linux). Anyone could help me?

Comment: Did you select `Add include paths exported from referenced projects` in Compile tab in Makemake options?

Comment: I didn't, but I did mark it now and I have the same error. Of course What I did is: right click on the project -> Properties -> omnet++ -> makemake -> src -> options on the right -> compile